# Get specific row from a subquery using aggregate function

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am trying to get a specific row from a subquery, but I cannot use an aggregate function in a WHERE clause and I have read that I should be using a HAVING clause but I have no idea where to start.

This is my current sql statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    select ID, SUM(BALANCE) AS Balance FROM bankacc GROUP BY ID
)A
```

I will get :

```
ID | Balance

1  |  30

2  |  40

3  |  50

4  |  50
```

I need the rows with the `MAX(Balance)`, but I have no idea where to start, please help.

Comment: Means you want only row having ID 3, because Balance is MAX?

Comment: So do you want both 3rd & 4th row in your result?

Comment: Yes, there will probably be people having the same balance

Comment: Please check my ans, specially 2nd query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With window function:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE ( ID INT, Amount MONEY )

INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( 1, 10 ),
        ( 1, 10 ),
        ( 1, 10 ),
        ( 2, 5 ),
        ( 2, 20 ),
        ( 3, 50 )


SELECT  ID ,
        Amount
FROM    ( SELECT    ID ,
                    SUM(Amount) AS Amount ,
                    RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY SUM(Amount) DESC ) AS rn
          FROM      @t
          GROUP BY  ID
        ) t
WHERE   rn = 1
```

With `TOP` and `TIES`:

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES
        ID ,
        SUM(Amount) AS Amount
FROM    @t
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY Amount   desc
```

These versions will return rows where sum will be max, not just top 1 row.

Output:

```
ID  Amount
3   50.00
```

Comment: Order by ID Desc? what if ID 1 has MAX Amount?

Comment: @AK47, thanks, of course there should be `ORDER BY SUM(Amount) DESC`

Answer (score 2):

you can wrap it in a subquery:

```
SELECT q.id, max(q.b)
FROM
(
    select ID, SUM(BALANCE) b FROM bankacc GROUP BY ID
) q
group by q.id
```

or order them in dessending order and get first record:

```
select top 1 ID, SUM(BALANCE) b FROM bankacc GROUP BY ID order by b desc
```

in MySQL you need to use limit 1 instead of top 1

Comment: this returns to me the same thing as my original statement and what if i have 2 or more IDs with the same balances?

Comment: `order by 2 desc` - this is one of the worst bad practice in SQL

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri why  `worst bad`? you could mention it with logical reason, because maybe someone don't know it

Comment: @Farhęg, it is non relational, it can lead to bug if some columns added before balance.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri great +1 for your comment, I didn't consider he/she may add some columns without noticing to order clause, however answer edited.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be simple.

-- This will return only 1 record, even if there are 2 records for MAX same amount

```
SELECT  top 1 ID ,
        Amount
FROM    ( SELECT    ID ,
                    SUM(Amount) AS Amount 
          FROM      Table
          GROUP BY  ID
        ) t
Order by Amount desc,ID asc
```

Using Window function : This will return what you want.

```
SELECT  ID ,
        Amount
FROM    ( SELECT    ID ,
                    SUM(Amount) AS Amount ,
                    RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY SUM(Amount)  DESC ) AS rnk
          FROM      Table
          GROUP BY  ID
        ) t
WHERE   rnk = 1
```

Comment: I tried your second query, it just gives me row 3, not both row 3 and 4. ID 3 and 4 have the same balance.

Comment: Here should be rank instead of row_number. this is copy paste epic fail.

Comment: Thanks, it works! Is there any way to do this without using window function?

Comment: Incorrect first statement and copy pasted second statement from my answer accepted.

Comment: Please don't feel offended, I am the one who has upvoted your answer. Also your answer was having some issue, I pointed you that. In between I added my answer & you helped me to correct it. I agree that I have referred your answer.